# MapKit, setting the view

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

So I setup some debugging to log the `visibleMapRect` when I change the view of my map. When I get the view the way I want it, I noted down the values and in the `viewDidLoad` I set the mapView to that rect. However its not the same view. It is zoomed out more, so what I was looking at is centered on screen but there is more on screen as well.

How do I set the mapView to be the same as I had it set to?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    MKMapRect mRectHawaii;
    mRectHawaii.origin.x = 16077095.369230;
    mRectHawaii.origin.y = 117612734.225784;
    mRectHawaii.size.width = 698548.708173;
    mRectHawaii.size.height = 393548.573271;

    [self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mRectHawaii animated:NO];
}


- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    MKMapRect mRect = mapView.visibleMapRect;

    NSLog(@"(%f, %f) (%f, %f)", mRect.origin.x, mRect.origin.y, mRect.size.width, mRect.size.height);
}
```

Comment: multiple version (6&7)

Comment: Maybe `setVisibleMapRect:edgePadding:animated:` is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
 MKMapRect zoomRect = MKMapRectNull;


        MKMapPoint annotationPoint = MKMapPointForCoordinate(annotation.coordinate);
        MKMapRect pointRect = MKMapRectMake(annotationPoint.x, annotationPoint.y, 0.1, 0.1);
        if (MKMapRectIsNull(zoomRect)) {
            zoomRect = pointRect;
        }else{
            zoomRect = MKMapRectUnion(zoomRect, pointRect);
        }
    }

    [[self mapview] setVisibleMapRect:zoomRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50) animated:YES];
```